# Does OpenSSL provide any post quantum asymmetric algorithms?

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, public-key-encryption, post-quantum-cryptography

I'm familiar with classical encryption algorithms and mathematics, like RSA and ECC, but just out of interest. I'm not a specialist in this field. I'd like to start a long-term project, but since I'm not a cryptographer, it's very difficult to research this topic and get a clear and correct answer. I'm looking to use OpenSSL as a black-box for this purpose.

**My question:** Does OpenSSL provide any post quantum asymmetric algorithms for both encryption and/or signatures?

If not, are there any plans in the future to support this?

PS: Please note that I'm not asking for software recommendation as I understand this is off-topic. I'm asking about OpenSSL here and its supported algorithms.

Comment: If you down-vote, please explain what's wrong with the question so that I can fix it. This is exactly why I'm starting to hate stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not.

However, you should monitor the [Open Quantum Safe project](https://openquantumsafe.org), which creates a library that operates with OpenSSL with the view of introducing post-quantum safe algorithms into OpenSSL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know about that project, but I was hoping OpenSSL did something about PQ.

Comment: Not yet.  :). Maybe someday!